# Javascript glitchy game

Tags: javascript

I have a game and when you hit the Obs's you get a game over screen. On it has a retry button and it resets it, it works most of the time but after the third or fourth retry it does not reset it. It just keeps it where it is. Why does it do that? Below is the code I used for the reset and a link. Thanks.

```
if (collides($(value), $('#player'))) {
                  $('#levelOne').stop();
                  $('#player').css('border', 'solid 1px yellow');
                  //GAME OVER SCREEN START
                  $('#GameOver').fadeIn();
                  $('#retry').click(function () {
                      $('#GameOver').fadeOut();

                      // NEW LOGIC
                      $("#levelOne").css('margin-top', '-1520px');
                      $("#player").css('border', 'solid 1px green')
                      $("#player").css('margin-left', '223px');
                      $('#levelComplete').hide();
                      $('#levelOne').animate({
                          'margin-top': '+=1520px'
                      }, speed);
                      handleCollisions()

                  });
              }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/38bod36e/101/

Comment: you should do a full reset on restart. when you collide and restart in a box you quickly exceed maximum call stack

Answer (score 1):

You are constantly adding click event listeners in the `handleCollisions` function (this part: `$('#retry').click(function () {`), which is bound to kill your performance sooner or later because the number of events created/called will get insanely big. That is something you need to take care of to get rid of the glitches.

I moved the click handler function outside and it works just fine. I've also disabled the console log on every frame because it kills the performance as well.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/38bod36e/103/

Be careful with stuff like that if you want a consistent performance. See in the console how the number of events grows with every frame rendered in your original code: http://jsfiddle.net/38bod36e/105/